# Prevent scientific notation when created an excel file in asp.net using response

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I'm creating an excel file using the response object in an asp.net web application.  Some of the long numeric values are being converted to scientific notation.  I would like to keep the code I'm using because it prevents time-out issues I received due to the size of the data.  Can someone offer any advice on how to modify the existing code to prevent columns from being converted to scientific notation?

```
    Response.Clear()
    Response.Buffer = True
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=test.csv")
    Response.Charset = ""
    Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache)
    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls"


    Try
        sqlconn.Open()

        Dim dr As SqlDataReader = sqlcmd.ExecuteReader()
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        'Add Header

        For count As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 1
            If dr.GetName(count) IsNot Nothing Then
                sb.Append(dr.GetName(count))
            End If
            If count < dr.FieldCount - 1 Then
                sb.Append(",")
            End If
        Next
        Response.Write(sb.ToString() & vbLf)
        Response.Flush()
        'Append Data

        While dr.Read()
            sb = New StringBuilder()

            For col As Integer = 0 To dr.FieldCount - 2
                If Not dr.IsDBNull(col) Then
                    sb.Append(dr.GetValue(col).ToString().Replace(",", " "))
                End If
                sb.Append(",")
            Next
            If Not dr.IsDBNull(dr.FieldCount - 1) Then
                sb.Append(dr.GetValue(dr.FieldCount - 1).ToString().Replace(",", " "))
            End If
            Response.Write(sb.ToString() & vbLf)
            Response.Flush()
        End While
        dr.Dispose()
    Catch ex As Exception

    Finally

        sqlconn.Close()
    End Try
    Response.End()
```

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, the issue is happening because Excel is reading your data and guessing at what type of data it is and if it thinks they are numbers for things that are really text with numbers in it, then it starts applying scientific notation.

The only way I know of to force this to not happen is to use the `Excel API` and force a column to a particular format, like this:

```
xlApp.Columns("A:A").Select()
xlApp.Selection.NumberFormat = "@"
```

Note: This will select column A in your worksheet and then force the number format to text.

Comment: Another way is to prepend an apostrophe to the numeric string. e.g.
"'0123456"  This also deals with the truncation of the leading zeros problem.

Comment: The prepended apostrophe appears in the excel column.  Is there anyway to prevent it from appearing?

Comment: -1: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)

Answer (score -1):

Hi I know this question is a bit old but I just want to share my idea on how to prevent the scientific notations in excel generated files. I have tried the "@" but the cells on the respective row/column where I applied the .NumberFormat has a warning icon on it. It says that converting a number to text is invalid.

I have here a solution in which I personally used as a fixed to that warning, you can use a "#" instead "@". Here is the sample.

```
mySheet.Range("A:A").NumberFormat = "#"
```

I think using the "@" is for text data type only that is why the warning occurs.
Hope this helps.

Comment: -1: It is a horrible idea to use Office Interop from ASP.NET or another server technology. These APIs were written for use in a desktop application, for automating Office (a suite of desktop applications). Server applications are different in many ways that make it a very, very bad idea to use Office Interop in them. It's also unsupported by Microsoft, and may violate your Office license. See [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/257757)